# Where is the default fish completion style defined or how do I style the fish completion options listing?

Tags: shell, fish

I'm using `complete -c cl -o editz -f -xa '(cl -autocomplete 15 | sed "s/:/\\t/" | sed -r "s/^(.{60}).*/\1/")'` to dynamically feed the latest 15 entires in a log program to fish for tab-completion. It works very well but I'd like to style how fish presents them. I'd like to avoid the two columns and left-align the description text.

I assume there is a function that defines how `complete -xa` handles the incoming list. Where (which file) is this definition located and is it possible to alter how this list is presented?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to avoid the two columns and left-align the description text.

Neither of these are configurable in fish.

> I assume there is a function that defines how complete -xa handles the incoming list.

There isn't a script function that defines how this is handled. It's all hard-coded in C++. Should be in https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/src/pager.cpp